# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkinsproject for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries

I have to start using shared library for my jenkins pipeline jobs. I have make seprate git repo as well.

But i am getting error as mentioned above while build jenkins job?

Have any idea why its showing me error?

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: xxx for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:271)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:4)
at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

thanks in advance

Comment: The error is quite self-explainable `No such property: jenkinsproject`

Comment: i think issue is with scriptsecurity plugin and its not allowed to jenkins job to run with shared libraries pipeline

Comment: @daggett do you have any such solutions for this issue or have you faced like this?

Comment: there is no such property with name `jenkinsproject` - just remove it from your code as a simple solution.

Comment: this issue is resolved after upgrading all plugins.